# git get new file from repository

Tags: git

In the below commands I am trying to get update a local repository. But please let me know how to do it. In SVN we use `svn update` to get the latest files from the trunk but how to do the same in git

Following are the commands

```
    mkdir git_tut
    git init --bare
    git clone git_tut rep1

    cd rep1
    //create a file testfile.txt and add it  
    //This file contains the content as from rep
    git add testfile.txt    
    git commit -a -m "comments"
    git push origin master
    //Now cd ../ and create a new reopo as rep2
    git clone git_tut rep2
    //Now in rep2
    //In file testfile.txt add a new line and push to git_tut
```

How to update the new file in rep1 like `svn up`

Comment: you need to do a `git pull origin master`

Comment: And can u please tell me how to resolve a conflict in git and put down this in answer so that i can mark it as accepted

Comment: Cool, I've added it as an answer & attached my workflow for resolving conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do a `git pull origin master`

To resolve conflicts, I usually do the following:

```
`git diff` to see what the issues are and possibly manually fix them
`git revert the_filename` to revert changes if needed
`git add the_file` to add it to staging
`git commit -m "commit message"` to commit 
`git push origin master` to send it off
```

You should check out the following references:

http://rogerdudler.github.com/git-guide/

http://gitref.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can use git fetch
If there any conflicts and you want to merge it , git pull is better option.
git pull = git fetch + git merge.
To see manual page , git pull --help